# comments getting hidden behind username

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

I've noticed that comments are getting hidden behind the commenter's username. This seems to happen mainly in comments exactly one line long, causing the commenter's username to appear in the next line without any text in the same line.

I'm using firefox ob ubuntu 14.04.

***Example***:

[image]

Comment: Since I don't have Ubuntu running I can't say I fixed this for sure. I did push a change where the OP's box padding is lessened by 2 pixels vertically. Please let me know if this is still a problem for you. Our next production build should go out later tonight, so check in the morning. Thanks.

Comment: I think it's fixed, I'm not able to reproduce the original error on Ubuntu (Chrome or Firefox).

Comment: @Jin it is fixed! Now it appears correctly. Thank you.